# useFieldArray remove does not remove all fields

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form

I am new to ReactJS and have built a dynamic form using `useFieldArray` from react-hook-form. Then if I want to remove a form to a corresponding id via `remove(index)` the file is still the same

```js
interface FormValues {
  otherFormValues: OtherFormValues[];
  name: string;
}

interface OtherFormValues {
  file: File;
  name: string;
  age: number;
  address: string;
  // ...
}

export default function MyComponent(): JSX.Element {
  const { control, register, unregister, resetField } = useForm();
  const { fields, append, remove } = useFieldArray({
    control,
    name: 'my-form',
  });

  const fileInputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement | null>(null);

  return (
    // other components
    {({ getValues, setValue, watch }) => {
      return (
        <>
          {fields.map((field, index) => {
            return (
              <TextField
                name="name"
                value={AudioContext.getValues(`otherFormValues.${index}.name`) ?? ''}
                InputProps={{
                  readOnly: true,
                  endAdornment: (
                    <InputAdornment position="end">
                      <DeleteIcon
                        onClick={() => {
                          remove(index);
                          console.log(context.getValues(`otherFormValues`));
                        }}
                      />
                    </InputAdornment>
                  ),
                }}
              />
              <TextField
                label="name"
                {...register(`otherFormValues.${index}.name`)}
              />
              <TextField
                label="age"
                {...register(`otherFormValues.${index}.age`)}
              />
              <TextField
                label="address"
                {...register(`otherFormValues.${index}.address`)}
              />
              {/* some more */}
            );
          })}
          <input
            type="file"
            hidden
            accept=".csv"
            style={{ display: 'none' }}
            ref={fileInputRef}
            onChange={(event) => {
              const files = event.target.files;
              const amount = context.watch('otherFormValues').length;
              if (files) {
                const newFile = files[0];
                const existingFiles = context
                  .watch(`otherFormValues`)
                  .map((f) => f.file);

                const fileExists = existingFiles.some((existingFile) => {
                  return (
                    existingFile && existingFile.name === newFile.name
                  );
                });

                if (!fileExists) {
                  AudioContext.setValue(`otherFormValues.${amount}.file`, newFile);
                  append('my-form');
                } else {
                  console.log('file already selected');
                }
              }
            }}
          />
          <Button
            onClick={() => {
              if (fileInputRef.current) {
                fileInputRef.current.click();
              }
            }}
          >
            Select file
          </Button>
        </>
      );
    }}
  );
}
```

the log shows all fields are set to `undefined` except the file. The file is still as present as before.

Any ideas?